# Can't get Google Analytics to work...tracker not installed

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I've read other questions concerning this problem but they haven't been much of help so far.

I've made a test page to figure out if it's related to broken javascript elsewhere, but still to no avail. My code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-59026305-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script><body>
Redirect page
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Or check it out for yourself at http://www.slovo.be

I've set the main url in my Analytics settings to http://www.slovo.be/index.php.
I've also installed the Analytics Debugger extension for Chrome, and it looks to be sending out a beacon regardless.

Any ideas?

Comment: unrelated, but body should't be in head

Answer (score 0):

It can take a few days for the warning to disappear in the interface. Verify that you're getting data in the reports (real-time and standard) and that no filters are blocking your traffic. Otherwise you can ignore the warning if you're seeing data & seeing the requests being made.

But as taesu mentioned, your `<head>` tag should not wrap around the `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

As Philip has mentioned:

1. I've you just implemented the code, it takes a while for data to appear on Google Analytics.
2. Go on to your site and then open Google Analytics and check Real-Time Data (which is under the "Audience" Tab) and it should show 1 user (ie. you).

This is assuming that you have not filtered out your own IP address (If you have no idea what that means, then it means you haven't)

As an extra measure (if data is still not showing even after a few days), use a tool to check you've done everything correctly. http://www.checkmyanalytics.com (a tool I'm working on) will check if you're missing the code on any of your pages - among other useful stuff)

Hope this helps and good luck!